# How to define a class with dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to define a class with dynamic props like 'Methods'. I wrote this

```
type Methods = {
    [name:string]:Function
}

class App <M extends Methods> { 
    [name: keyof M] : M[name] // dont work
}

var methods = {
    action : Function,
    move : Function
}

type M = keyof typeof methods;

type myApp = App<typeof methods>;
```

but I get the following errors. Can these be fixed?

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

> 'name' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof name'?

> Return type of index signature from exported interface has or is using private name 'name'.

[Reproducible example](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx0RN)

Comment: *What* error do you get? Please [edit] your question to include it, don't only post links to external resources.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). Those only work for `type` declarations, not for `class`es though:

```
type App<M extends Methods> = { 
    [name in keyof M]: M[name];
}
```

<sup>([Full demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATAzlAvFA3gKCkKgG0A7AQwFsIAuNYAJwEtSBzAXRqgDEBXUgMbAmSUngC+ePKEhQAgmDAAeGFAgAPYBFLpY8ZOgB8WXFAJEyVaCygBrCCCQAzWJ1iXq7ANwSpAN3IGKGpEVAxsfCIociERUiguPkFhUQAac0JKJD9oRP5Y0V9pcGhVbHtHFxkIZ2D9MJ9i2UoQBTATNqVq2pCDNENGvCA))</sup>

If you actually want to define a class, you need to do it with a concrete type:

```
var methods = {
    action: Function,
    move: Function
}
type MyApp = App<typeof methods>;

class TheApp implements MyApp {
    action!: typeof Function;
    move!: typeof Function;
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, methods);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is such a constraints with classes and interfaces :_